# Full screen mapkit map

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have mapkit view on iphone and i want to show all world in view, but then i use

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude=0.0f;
region.center.longitude=0.0f;
region.span.latitudeDelta=180.0f;
region.span.longitudeDelta=360.0f;
[map setRegion:region];
```

I have error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '
How fix it?

Comment: Thats strange... Your code works ok for me on both device and simulator (3.0 firmware)

Comment: Ohh, now i test it on 3.0 firmware and don't have errors, but screen not cover all world too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use "regionThatFits"?

[mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:TRUE];